# Magento 2 - Failed Authorize.net Transactions Are Not Being Canceled and Not Getting a Response from Auth.net

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, authorize.net

I have a pair of sites I manage that are on Magento 2.2.4 and 2.2.5. Both are using Authorize.net Direct Post and I have applied the Authorize.net MD5 patch from Magento to utilize the signature key instead of MD5. Both sites are able to properly process valid cards but failed transactions do not get canceled as expected. This was hit and miss prior to the patch so that might not be related.

I have both sites properly calling the Magento cron on a schedule for every two minutes. Even after the cron has run, the order is not canceled and remains in pending. I have set Direct Post to Authorize & Capture, but that did not have any impact.

```
The reporting of this transaction to the Merchant has timed out. An e-mail has been sent to the merchant informing them of the error. The following is the result of the attempt to charge your credit card. 

This transaction has been declined.
```

This is what I get as a response from transact.dll. I have Debug enabled for Direct Post so I get logs and I am not receiving a response from Authorize.net. I'm gathering that will be my issue but what would prevent Magento from seeing the response?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED

This is a Know Magento issue.

There is a fix already that will be realeased on Magento 2.3.2

You can extend the current file and apply the path by your self.

Please check the following issue with the commit that have the fix on it:

- issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22373
- Commit with the hot fix: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/dd7cb583b112f82ba58ef87d612631ac0eb1c57c

I suggest to extend the current file into app/code until the new version comes out.

Comment: I have installed the sha512 patch and am using the sigkey instead of md5. Even not using the md5 gives me the same results. When a transaction fails, it should cancel the order. The order cancel is not happening. Auth.net works fine on successful payments so I know it works.

Comment: Im getting the same issue, maybe this is a magento bug, when the order is rejected on Autorize the order is being placed on magento as processing...

Comment: Please check my updated answer

Comment: This occurs in 2.2.x as well as 2.3.0, which do not use Accept.js. I can check around the same places for the prior method.

Thanks for the tip though.